# malloc in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, malloc, fgets, x86-16

I need to receive input from user and I am required to use malloc to init the buffer first. I can't find any example online.

This is the buffer:

```
 section .bss
        buffer:
                resb 80                     ;store my input
```

How is it done? Is this ok? (it compiles but I don't think it works...)

```
    push 80
    push buffer
    call malloc
    add esp, 8
```

or maybe this? (this doesn't compile)

```
push 80
push buffer
call malloc
add esp, 8 
mov buffer, [eax]
```

The thing is that when I give the buffer the input 0, it prints 2608
instead of 48 as the ASCII value should print.

Input 1 -> gives 2609 accordingly. So my guess is that somehow the buffer has values it's not supposed to have.

This is the fgets part (it works ok)

```
 push dword [stdin]             ;fgets need 3 param
    push dword 80                   ;max lenght
    push dword buffer               ;input buffer
    call fgets
    add esp, 12                     ;remove 3 push from stuck
```

and this is the print part:

```
push dword [buffer]             ;push string to stuck
push INT_FORMAT                     ; its INT_FORMAT:DB "%d", 10, 0
call printf             
add esp, 8              ;remove pushed argument
```

Comment: `malloc` only takes one argument: the number of bytes to allocate. SO you do not want to push the `buffer` as an argument. The pointer to the allocated buffer is returned by the function, so will be in `eax` upon return. You don't need `buffer` reserving 80 bytes since you're dynamically allocating 80 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) has one `DWORD` parameter, which is the size in bytes to allocate, so it should be called:

```
push <size>
call malloc
add esp, 4
; now eax points to an allocated buffer of the requested size
mov [eax], ebx ; will set the first 4 bytes of the buffer to ebx (etc...)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer.
Is it important if i define my buffer in the rodata or the bss?

Comment: You don't "define" your buffer, `malloc` gives you an address for one. Save it wherever you want.